# SpringBoot EntityManagerFactory not found

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, gradle, intellij-idea

So, trying to run first sprinboot application with JPA implementation and got the following error :

```
Description:

Field personneDAO in com.example.demo.controller.PersonneController required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

tried to add @Repositoy on my repo, and @EnableJpaRepositories to the main, but it doesn't helps...

the repository (nothing too fancy):

```
@Repository
public interface PersonneDAO extends JpaRepository<Personne, Integer>{
}
```

the main :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages ="com.example.demo.repository")

public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

gradle dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper')
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.2.16.Final'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: '2.0.6.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '6.5.1.jre9-preview'
}
```

Any ideas guys? :/

PS : forgot the application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix = /WEB-INF/
spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost/DB_TEST
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=Pa$$w0rd
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Comment: JPA will not get auto-configured without `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` as a dependency. With the dependency in place, you shouldn't even need `@EnableJpaRepositories`. Also, you may remove `spring-data-jpa` as `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` already depends on that.

Comment: Well, that was it! works fine now. Thanks for the advice with spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, @crizzis! can you post as an answer so I can mark as solution? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA will not get auto-configured without `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` as a dependency. With the dependency in place, you shouldn't even need `@EnableJpaRepositories`.

Also, you may remove `spring-data-jpa` as `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` already depends on that.