# Spring JPA - entitymanagerfactory that could not be found, why?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-data-jpa

Please tell me how to overcome it.
I use Gradle while building I get an error:

```
Description:
Field userRepository in com.fitness.api.controller.UserController required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

Action:
Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

Application file:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.test.api.repository")
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration

## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
# MySQL properties
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = 1234

## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.0.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}
```

Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt"},
        allowGetters = true)
public class User implements Serializable {
}
```

It seems to do the lessons, but can not build a project.
For a long time I can not solve this problem, maybe someone knows the solution.

Comment: Are you sure that the above compiles?  I'm not using gradle but I don't see the dependencies for spring-data-jpa.

Comment: Do u have `compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: '2.0.6.RELEASE'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SpringBoot EntityManagerFactory not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49759623/springboot-entitymanagerfactory-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

If you exclude `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` class then you have to set `DataSource` bean manually.

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```